# ASP.NET - DLL w/ Unmanaged dependency fails on restart, works after touching bin/

Tags: iis-7, asp.net

I'm new to IIS and ASP.NET so please excuse that in advance.

We have an ASP.NET application that references a Managed C++/CLI DLL that has various unmanaged C++ dependencies.  The Managed DLL is deployed to the application's bin folder, and the unmanaged DLLs live in a subfolder of bin/.

When I do a full iisreset (or reboot the server), I get an ASP.NET warning of an unhandled exception in the event log.  From there, I get the exact same exception whenever I run the code which requires the Managed DLL.

However...the problem vanishes as soon as I touch anything in the bin/ folder.  From then on, the code that uses the Managed DLL works perfectly.  Until the next IIS reset.

Any thoughts or pointers are appreciated.  Obviously I'm looking for

-Ryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For posterity, I work with Ryan, and this was resolved.

We narrowed down the issue by realizing that touching files within the Application Site directory ("served" directory) triggers an Application Restart. We found a `Global.asax.cs` file that listens to the `Application_Start` ASP.NET lifecycle event, and there was an error within that listener. [Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx).